# How do I show this function is a bijection?

Tags: mathematical-economics

Let $\geq$ be a partial order on a set $X$. For each $x\in X$, let $F(x)\equiv \{a\in X:a\geq x\}$ and $\mathcal{F}\equiv\{F(x):x\in X\}$. I want to show that $F:X\to\mathcal{F}$ is a bijection.

First I have shown that it is an injection. Take $x,x'\in X, x\neq x'$. Suppose by contradiction $F(x)=F(x').$ Since $x\in F(x),x\in F(x')\implies x\geq x'$. Similarly, $x'\geq x$. Thus, $x=x'$, which is a contradiction. thus, $F(x)\neq F(x')$.

I'm having trouble showing that $F$ is a surjection. How do I do that?

Comment: It is trivially a surjection; $\mathcal{F}$ is defined as the range of $F$.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker Hi! Could you elaborate more on this? Suppose $X=\{1,2,3,4\}$. Then $F(1)=\{1,2,3,4\},F(2)=\{2,3,4\},F(3)=\{3,4\},F(4)=\{4\}$. How is $\mathcal{F}$ defined in this case? And why is $\mathcal{F}$ defined as the range of $F$ make $F$ a trivial surjection?

Comment: $\mathcal{F}$ is defined as above. And that a function is surjective means exactly that it's range is the whole codomain.